# Trigger syntax wrong

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

[image: Snippet of ER-diagram]

I'm trying to create a trigger to give "SumBeforeTaxes(from 'order')" a value.

The "SumBeforeTaxes" is itemQuantity(from 'order_item') x price ('from itemsinstock').

So if one has ordered 3 items at 10 USD each, the "SumBeforeTaxes" would be 3 x 10 (30 in total).  Likewise, if one has ordered 3 items at 10 USD each AND 2 items at 15 each, the "SumBeforeTaxes" should be 3x10 + 2x15 (60 in total).

Here's what I've tried so far - but I keep getting syntax errors. I'm also not sure my triggers (despite the syntax errors) are correct.

1st attempt:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `orderdb`.`order_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `order_item` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET getItemPrice = (SELECT Price FROM itemsinstock);

INSERT orderdb.'order'
SET SumBeforeTax = itemQuantity * getItemPrice;

END
```

2nd attempt:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `orderdb`.`order_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `order_item` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


SET getItemPrice = (SELECT Price FROM itemsinstock);

INSERT INTO orderdb.'order' (SumBeforeTax) VALUES (new.itemQuantity * getItemPrice);

END
```

3rd attempt:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `orderdb`.`order_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `order_item` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

declare getItemPrice DOUBLE;

SET getItemPrice = (SELECT Price FROM itemsinstock WHERE ItemID = new.itemID);

INSERT INTO orderdb.'order'(SumBeforeTax) VALUES (itemQuantity * getItemPrice);

END
```

Can I get a little help on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserve word in `MySQL` and thus you need to escape it like below using backtique for your `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO orderdb.`order`(SumBeforeTax) VALUES (itemQuantity * getItemPrice);
```

For any syntactical clarification refer [Documentation On CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

You might want to change your code like below in that case using an `UPDATE` statement rather:

```
BEGIN
declare getItemPrice DOUBLE;

SELECT Price INTO getItemPrice FROM itemsinstock WHERE ItemID = new.itemID;

UPDATE orderdb.`order` SET SumBeforeTax = new.itemQuantity * getItemPrice
WHERE OrderID = 101;
```

Comment: itemQuantity is from the table "order_item".  Bottom one :)

I just added the '' to order, but I still get a syntax error. I'll try to visit the link you just posted :)

Comment: Ahh! That worked :) I see that update works better. Thanks a lot :)